# Flexdashboard doesn't render inputs after uiOutput

Tags: shiny, flexdashboard

So I've been struggling with this line of code. My uiOutput function seems to kill everything underneath it.
When I run the document, nothing appears underneath my **uiOutput("SELECT_STAGE_1")**
However, when I delete this line, the rest of the code gets rendered and when I put it back, my **uiOutput("SELECT_STAGE_1")** appears but nothing else afterwards.
Did I do something wrong on my **"renderUI"** line in the setup?

````
    ---
    title: "ALICE"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: columns
        vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny 

    ---
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(leaflet)

    STAGES <- read_csv2("20191122_STAGES.csv")
    STATIONS <- read_csv2("20191122_STATIONS.csv")
    TRAJETS <- read_csv2("20191122_TRAJETS.csv")

    output$SELECT_STAGE_1 <- renderUI({
      liste_stage_1 <- STAGES$ETABLISSEMENT[STAGES$DEPT == input$DEPT_1]
      selectInput("SELECT_STAGE_1",
                  label = NULL,
                  choices = liste_stage_1,
                  selected = NULL)
    })



    Column {data-width=1000}
    Hello
    selectInput("DEPT_1", 
                label = NULL,
                choices = sort(unique(STAGES$DEPT)),
                selected = "AUCUN")

    uiOutput("SELECT_STAGE_1")

    sliderInput("WANTED_TIME", "Wanted time", 5, 90, 10)

    checkboxInput("UNAUTRE", label = "I need a second entry", value = FALSE)

    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.UNAUTRE == true",
      selectInput("DEPT_2", 
                  label = NULL,
                  choices = sort(unique(STAGES$DEPT)),
                  selected = "AUCUN"))
````

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I was searching here to ask this same question. It's not just with renderUI, but any render function seems to prevent others from appearing in the same section as separated by ###